# How to resolve "Call to undefined function" after upgrade to 4.7.27 CRM_Core_SelectValues::datePluginToPHPFormats()

Tags: extension, 4.7.27

We have just upgraded WP to 4.8.3 and Civi to 4.7.27, now getting the following error from one of our extensions:-

> Call to undefined method CRM_Core_SelectValues::datePluginToPHPFormats()

The offending code snippet is below:-

```
protected function getFormattedFieldValue($value, $field) {
if ($field['data_type'] == 'Date' && !empty($value)) {
```

> ```
> $actualPHPFormats = CRM_Core_SelectValues::datePluginToPHPFormats();
> ```

```
  $dateFormat = (array) CRM_Utils_Array::value($field['date_format'], $actualPHPFormats);
  $value = CRM_Utils_Date::processDate($value, NULL, FALSE, implode(" ", $dateFormat));
} elseif (!empty($field['option_group_id']) && $value) {
  try {
    $value = civicrm_api3('OptionValue', 'getvalue', array(
      'return' => 'label',
      'option_group_id' => $field['option_group_id'],
      'value' => $value,
    ));
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
  }
}
return $value;
```

}

Any ideas how I can correct this code? I can't find the function in the docs: https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/v47/phpdoc/CRM_Core_SelectValues.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After searching on Jira for the funciton, nothing came up, so searched the codebase from our backup and found the function was in the file: civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Date.php:1788

It's now gone, along with a lot of other ones!

So I've added the array of date formats to the code to workaround the issue.

```
//$actualPHPFormats = CRM_Core_SelectValues::datePluginToPHPFormats();
  $actualPHPFormats = array(
    "mm/dd/yy" => 'm/d/Y',
    "dd/mm/yy" => 'd/m/Y',
    "yy-mm-dd" => 'Y-m-d',
    "dd-mm-yy" => 'd-m-Y',
    "dd.mm.yy" => 'd.m.Y',
    "M d" => 'M j',
    "M d, yy" => 'M j, Y',
    "d M yy" => 'j M Y',
    "MM d, yy" => 'F j, Y',
    "d MM yy" => 'j F Y',
    "DD, d MM yy" => 'l, j F Y',
    "mm/dd" => 'm/d',
    "dd-mm" => 'd-m',
    "yy-mm" => 'Y-m',
    "M yy" => 'M Y',
    "M Y" => 'M Y',
    "yy" => 'Y',
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that function in the latest release so it seems to be fixed since 4.7.27 (latest is 5.0.0)